# fancybox.open() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

this code works in  FF, but not in IE, the popup fancybox without any content, suspect the content:$response.html() not working in IE

Please help!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'loginSelectAccount',
    data:{clientId:$username, password:$password, activationCode:$activationCode},
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function (data) {
                 var $response = $(data);
                 var $retval = $response.find('#multiRecord').attr('value');

                 if ($retval == 'false'){
                     $.fancybox.close(true);
                     $("#logFormid").submit();
                  } else if($retval == 'true'){
                      $response.find('#username').attr('value',$username);
                      $response.find('#password').attr('value',$password);
                      $response.find('#activationCode').attr('value',$activationCode);
                      $response.find('#pageTryLogin').attr('value',$pageTryLogin);
                      $.fancybox.open({
                          content : $response.html(),
                          afterClose : function() {
                              $("#select_login").show();
                         }
                      });
                  }
             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the $response.html() in a variable before sending it as a parameter...